# Bit shifting fails after the 20th time (Solidity)

Tags: ethereum, solidity

my goal is to bit shift a maxed uint256 so that zeros are iteratively added to the right side:

```
...1111111111111...
```

becomes

```
...1111111111000...
```

I the use the new shifted position as a mask.

After about 20 something iterations my code stops working properly.

Does anyone have any insight on the matter?

Is there an EVM overflow limit?

I am new to solidity... If anyone has a better way of debugging variables besides listening to events please be understanding and explain the approach.

```
uint256 public MAXUINT256 = 2*256 - 1;

for (uint256 i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
      var mask = MAXUINT256 * (2 ** i);
      var key = signature & bytes32(mask);

      if (Cell[key] != address(0)) {
        NEW_SIG = uint(sha256(signature,Cell[key]));
        Callback ctx = Callback(Cell[key]);
        ctx.ERNG_CALLBACK(NEW_SIG);

        if (i == bit) {
          Cell[key] = msg.sender;
        } else {
          Cell[key] = address(0);
        }
      } else {
        if (i == bit) {
          Cell[key] = msg.sender;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use Remix (http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity) to debug your contract.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation of `mask` overflows at `i >= 248`.

Was that really your intention?

BTW, `MAXUINT256 = 2*256 - 1` doesn't make much sense literally, since the actual `MAXUINT256` is in fact `2**256 - 1`. Of course, using this value would get your computation of `mask` overflowing for every value of `i`, so you probably need to clarify your intentions in general.